# allow apostrophes when using htmlentities

Tags: php, mysql

I have this:

```
<?php

if( !empty($_SESSION['descr']) )
{
    $descr = htmlentities($_SESSION['descr'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE,'utf-8' );
    $descr = stripslashes($descr);
    echo "<textarea cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\" name=\"descr\" >".$descr."</textarea>";
}
else
{
    echo "<textarea cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\" name=\"descr\" ></textarea>"; 
}       
?>
```

USING ---ENT_IGNORE-- WORKS BUT NOT SAFE I READ

The problem is if a user enters an apostrophe then it shoots an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' "

It works using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but I want to use `htmlentities()`.

Comment: I think there's code missing. You haven't used `mysql_real_escape_string()` in the code you've given. And what you've given works when `descr` has an apostrophe.

Comment: Aside: You've duplicated code. Instead of having the echo line twice, in the else set `$descr=''` and move the first instance of the echo to after the condition (and remove the one that's inside else)

Comment: @ popnoodles, I've tried it using $descr = mysql_real_escape_string($descr); but it didn't work either, same error. My browser is set to utf-8 too. what do you mean by duplicated code?

Comment: Where do you get this error? On your page? I've coped that PHP, set `$_SESSION['descr']="asasdas\"dasd'asd\'asd";` and it runs fine. By duplicating code, I mean see there are two lines in one condition echoing the same thing with one minor change, a change which could be set inside the condition and the echo outside. If you find yourself using copy and paste your own code, stop and think "can I do this with less code?"

Comment: Rocks, like I said half an hour ago, there is no way that PHP is outputting a SQL error because there is nothing it in that performs a SQL query. `You have an error in your SQL syntax` is not due to this code. Please post more.

Comment: **NO!** Do *not* use `htmlentities` as a replacement for proper escaping of user input into SQL.  That is absurd and **dangerous**.  It's *absurd* because `htmlentities` is for escaping HTML, not SQL.  It's *dangerous* because with improper escaping, you will leave yourself open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you the, use `str_replace();` to change the `'` into its html form of the quote which is `&#39;` before submitting it into mysql? Or use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) instead and not worry about it all-together???

Or perhaps you should check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114308/htmlentities-with-exceptions) link in SE, which is about making exceptions with/for `htmlentities();`?

Comment: @popnoodles he could use javascript to get by that. OR string_replace to replace it with `'` when echoing. So, overall. He will have to use string_replace twice. 1 when submitting, 2 when echoing. It is cumbersome, but not undoable.

Comment: I think actually you meant use str_replace and don't use htmlentities which would output `'` but I don't think any of this is necessary, once given the code that's producing the error. What we've been given is not what's causing a SQL error - there's no SQL execution in it.