# How to replace html line breaks after applying htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, html

I hope you can help you as you always do, thanks.

I have a form to input information in a textarea, I let the users write html tags because sometimes they would want to literaly write the html tags, so if they write something like this as input:

```
<h1>This is the input content</h1>
I like Pizza
I like Cheese
This is the end of the input, as you see I pressed enter several times
```

I save the input using nl2br, something like this:

```
$textForDataBase = nl2br($_POST['input']);
```

Then the database value is something like this:

```
<h1>This is the input content</h1>
I like Pizza<br />I like Cheese<br />This is the end of the input, as you see I pressed enter several times
```

Then before displaying the content I apply `htmlspecialchars` to my string but I want that all html tags that's not a break line to be converted to html entities, So I tried to use preg_replace but i had no luck, What can I do?

```
$html = htmlspecialchars($val['descripcion']);
echo preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $html);
```

If I don't use htmlspecialchars the output would be something like:

## This is the input content

I like Pizza
I like Cheese
This is the end of the input, as you see I pressed enter several times

But if I use it:

```
<h1>This is the input content</h1>
I like Pizza<br />I like Cheese<br />This is the end of the input, as you see I pressed enter several times
```

The expected output would be:

```
<h1>This is the input content</h1>
I like Pizza
I like Cheese
This is the end of the input, as you see I pressed enter several times
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114308/htmlentities-with-exceptions

Comment: when u store input detail in db remove nl2br and store user detail as same as like input value and then when u display value first use htmlspecialchars and then use nl2br and finally echo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when u store input detail in db remove nl2br and store user detail as same as like input value and then when u display value first use htmlspecialchars and then use nl2br and finally echo it.

just change like this.

```
$textForDataBase = $_POST['input'];

$html = htmlspecialchars($val['descripcion']);
echo nl2br($html);
```

Comment: Great this was fast to do, and exactly what I needed, Thank you a lot man!

Comment: don't think it will allow h1 though.

Comment: That was the goal, h1 is displayed as plain text as I wanted.

Comment: I see, You wanted to convert h1 also to entities. (y)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use strip_tags();

```
<?php 
$string = "
<p>This is a p element</p><a href=''>An a element</a><h1>This is the input content</h1> I like Pizza<br />I like Cheese<br />This is the end of the input, as you see I pressed enter several times";

$output = strip_tags($string,"<br>");
echo $output;
```

Comment: Hey Haider, Thanks for your answer I didn't test it since Mahipal answer's worked for me but thanks anyway!